# Trigger Google Web Translate Element

Tags: jquery, google-translate

Since the google translation api is shutting down, I am trying to get the google translate web element to work across the entire session for a user, so that they do not have to change the select box option to their language on each different page.

The initial load function is given as follows:

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, "google_translate_element");
 };
```

Where google_translate_element is the div into which to put the select box. When the select box is in there it always has the class "goog-te-combo". I can change the value of the box using jQuery with no issue, eg. $('.goog-te-combo').val('fr') will change the box to French. 
But when I try to trigger the translation using $('.goog-te-combo').trigger() using all sorts  event types (change, click, mouseup, mousedown, etc) the translation never fires.

Does anyone know of a way to trigger the translation?

Comment: If you are simply trying to trigger the translate on dynamically loaded content, Google released an update very recently that should handle this for you. My problem proof-of-concept [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patridge/NQ4uE/) is now a proof-of-concept for the new system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't done this before but by looking in the inspector in Google Chrome, I'm seeing that google loads a file called main.js. Look in that file and you will probably get a clue how they trigger the switch. main.js is of course packed and minified so try using this one [JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/).

I will tho look at it more and get back to you :) Hope it helps!

**UPDATE**

The reason why you can't trigger the element like that seems to be because the select box is inside an iframe. You can't interact with an iframe of a different domain.

Comment: Damn, I had a feeling that might be it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is definitely not an iframe issue. The `div#google_translate_element` Google populates with a `select.goog-te-combo` is embedded in the page itself. Unfortunately, interacting with that `select` is just as unproductive. None of the event code you throw at it triggers whatever code Google has for switching languages.

Comment: There are two ways to select a language using the Google Translate Element. One is via the top bar that shows up if you have already chosen a language or your browser reports a language different from the page in question (done in an `iframe`, yes, but an anchor/JS system and not a `select` box). The other is via the placeholder `div` you give Google Translate to populate with some UI elements, a `select` being one such element. This `select` box is most definitely not in an `iframe` in any browser I have used (IE9, FF, Chrome). Google nests it two `div`s deep in your placeholder `div`.

Comment: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/patridge/NQ4uE/) for use in your favorite DOM-inspecting browser. It is for a [similar SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158296/google-translate-on-javascript-generated-content), but it still shows the structure GT injects (assuming you don't take into account the jsFiddle iframes).

Answer (score 13):

This is an old question but I'll answer since i had the same problem and got around it.
I had to get the DOM from jQuery and fire and execute.

```
 function fireEvent(element,event){
     console.log("in Fire Event");
    if (document.createEventObject){
            // dispatch for IE
            console.log("in IE FireEvent");
        var evt = document.createEventObject();
        return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
    }
    else{
            // dispatch for firefox + others
            console.log("In HTML5 dispatchEvent");
            var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
            return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
 }
```

And I call it using

```
 var jObj = $('.goog-te-combo');
 var db = jObj.get(0);
 jObj.val(Lang);
 fireEvent(db, 'change');
```

Comment: This worked for me but it was generating a lot of "Max stack reached". Only change I had to make was change the 2nd parameter of initEvent into 'false'. So, this line worked fine: `evt.initEvent(event, false, true );`. Really hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

I have been having problems with this subject all day too :). But I have came to a conclusion.

Using the Chrome inspector tool I found that the Google translate select box is created AFTER the `window.load` event triggers! This is a big problem if you are trying to edit it using jQuery.

So I found a workaround. I know that's probably a wrong approach, but it is working for me. In my case I wanted (job related request) to change the first option of the select box, normally "Select you Language" to something different, ex. 123.

So I have implemented the following solution:

```
$(window).load(function () {
   setTimeout(function () {
      if ($("select.goog-te-combo option:first").val()=='')
      {
         $("select.goog-te-combo option:first").text("123");
      }
   }, 1000);
});
```

Hoping i have helped someone somehow.

Regards to all.

Comment: Thank you for the spelling correction, I'm Portuguese, i know that is not as excuse, next time i will try to type correctly :). Regards.

Answer (score 3):

The Google Translate Element language should carry between pages, though it can take a bit to kick in sometimes. In the earlier days, it wouldn't persist on Google Chrome, of all browsers, but it worked fine in Firefox and IE. As of writing this, it worked fine for me in Chrome, too.

If you want to force the translation to a particular language on the first page load, though, you can use a [Google-mentioned](http://translate.google.com/support/#0.1_webmaster) URL hash/fragment on page load. Since adding the hash after the page loads doesn't seem to trigger it, though, you will have to have it in a link that takes the user there the first load. Here is the hash syntax for forcing an immediate translation.

```
http://www.somedomain.com/#googtrans(en|TARGET_LANG)
```

For example, to force the page to translate into French as soon as the translate system can.

```
http://www.somedomain.com/#googtrans(en|fr)
```

I can't seem to decipher the meaning of the syntax, but I am only trying it on an originally-English page. `#googtrans(en|fr|ja)` results in Japanese but so does `#googtrans(en|ja|fr)`. Omitting the `en|` didn't seem to have any effect either. They don't go into detail on the specifics where [Google posted this tidbit](http://translate.google.com/support/#0.1_webmaster) (under "What is the Google Translate Web Element?").

Answer (score 2):

set the cookie googtrans to /en/XX and reload the page:

```
document.cookie = 'googtrans=/en/fr';
location.reload();
```

(of course, check if the cookie is not set before reloading, otherwise you'll get an infinite reload loop)

Comment: That was the best answer for me, and as a bonus if you load the translate bar script in async + init with a callback function, you can fire this immediately before the init to set the cookie without having to reload the page