# how to fetch content of a webpage post-translation (after window.load event??)

Tags: javascript, flask, fetch, google-translate

I'm currently coding a Flask application with a simplified version of my code below.

```
#app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

# Configure application"'

app = Flask(__name__)

# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded

app.config\["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"\] = True

@app.route("/")
def index():
return render_template("gettranslation.html")

@app.route("/translate")
def translate():
word = request.args.get("word")
lang = request.args.get("lang")
return render_template("translate.html", lang = lang, word=word)
```

The default webpage should log a translation of the given words, but instead it just logs the word before translation, though when visited the webpage being fetched takes a second to load and then shows the correct translation. How do I fetch this correct translation?

Here is simplified code from my two files:

```
<!--translate.html-->
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<p id="to-translate">{{word}}</p>

<script>
    var lang = "{{ lang }}";
    var lang = lang[0] + lang[1];
    console.log(lang);
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement(
            {
                pageLanguage: lang
            },
            "google_translate_element"
        );
    }
    window.href = window.href + "/#googtrans(" + lang + "|en)";
</script>
```

```
<!--gettranslation.html-->

<script>
    async function translate(sourcelang, destlang, word){
        var url = '/translate?word=' + word + "&lang=" + sourcelang + "/#googtrans(" + sourcelang   + "|" + destlang + ")";
        console.log(url);
        let response = await fetch(url, {redirect: 'follow'});
        let text = await response.text();
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
        var translation = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
        console.log(translation);
    }
    translate("fr", "en", "bonjour");
</script>
```

I thought using await or redirect: follow would work but neither did. I also got the idea to use #googletrans("source|dest") from this question: [Trigger Google Web Translate Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303021/trigger-google-web-translate-element?rq=1) if that's helpful.
Someone there saidthe Google translate select box is created after the window.load event triggers, so that is could be what is messing up my fetch request but if so I have no idea how to fix that.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The html template is rendered at server side, this might be causing the problem with your script.
Why don't you translate the words in flask and then send them to the template? There are libraries for that such as Flask-Googletrans [Flask-Googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Googletrans/).

You can translate in the view function:

```
from flask_googletrans import translator
ts = translator(app)
```

in the jinja template

```
<h1>{{ translate(text='your text', src='en', dest=['fr']) }}</h1>
```

I hope this helps